# Ionic 4 : How to fix a login page design

Tags: android, html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

I created a login page using ionic components, and i want to remove the lines under the inputs (Check the image below) and aligning all components in the middle of the screen.

I have tried this for aligning problem but nothing happened : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/i-want-ion-list-to-be-vertical-middle-and-horizontal-center/104483

Any suggestions please ??

[Image showing my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5OY3.png)

My files (CSS + HTML) :

```css
.image {
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 60%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 15px;
}

.text-input {
    text-align: center;
    background: #EDEFF0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #CDD2D4;
    padding: .5em;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1.2em;
}

.bttn {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 10px;
}

.mdiv {
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding class="mdiv">
  <ion-list lines="none" style="--ion-background-color: transparent">
    <ion-item>
      <img src="./../../assets/image/profile_pic.png" class="image"/>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input class="text-input" placeholder="Username" color="dark" [(ngModel)] = "username"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input class="text-input" type="password" placeholder="Password" color="dark" [(ngModel)]="password" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="mdiv">
    <ion-button class="bttn" shape="round" expand="full" color="success" (click)="login()">Log in</ion-button>
    <ion-button class="bttn" shape="round" expand="full" color="primary" (click)="doRegister()">Register</ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the aligning in the middle of the screen, i just managed to align content in the center horizontally by changing the `ion-list` to `ion-grid` and adding some properties to this one.
Here it is my last changes :

```css
.g-row {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ion-grid>
      <ion-row class="g-row">
        <img src="./../../assets/icon/login.png" class="image"/>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="g-row">
        <input class="text-input" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)] = "username" required/>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="g-row">
        <input class="text-input" type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" required/>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="g-row">
        <ion-button class="bttn login" mode="ios" shape="round" expand="full" (click)="login()">Log in</ion-button>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="g-row">
        <ion-button class="bttn register" mode="ios" shape="round" expand="full" (click)="doRegister()">Register</ion-button>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to use **CSS Custom Properties** for **ion-item** elements. Try the following **CSS Custom Properties** in the ***page or component's*** CSS file.

```
ion-item {
--highlight-color-valid: transparent;
--highlight-color-invalid: transparent;
--highlight-color-focused: transparent;
}
```

Please check the `ion-item` [CSS Custom Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties) for details.